# Low overhead performance debugging of Linux process scheduling

Tags: process, linux-kernel, scheduling, performance-testing

I am developing a high-performance multi-threaded application on the Linux platform. Ideally it is expected that all similar threads run with the same speed. However, there are some situation which One thread may execute while another is waiting for some other system latency. One example of system latency is timer interrupt handlers (LOC) which periodically runs on all CPU cores.

I am looking for a low overhead way to perform system performance debugging and detect such a situations. More specifically, I need to know WHY the application threads does not run with ideal speed and which system task is responsible for that wait state.

I think there are some performance statistics about process scheduling in `/proc/PID/sched` like `nr_wakeups`. However, I am more interested to know `WHY` rather than `How Many`.

I used to run `ftrace` while my application is running to monitor Linux kernel function activities and detect execution of any unusual tasks or interrupts. That was how I detect timer interrupt handlers put my application threads in wait state. However, this method has very high performance overhead and its hard to interpret the output.

Ideally, I can put my application threads to specific CPU cores. Then I need a performance monitoring tool which tells me what other processes has been executed on these CPU cores during the execution of my application.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hm. Try using Ftrace with the CONFIG_DYNAMIC_FTRACE option turned On.
From 'menuconfig' help:

> CONFIG_DYNAMIC_FTRACE:
>   │     │
>   │     │ This option will modify all the calls to function tracing
>   │     │ dynamically (will patch them out of the binary image and
>   │     │ replace them with a No-Op instruction) on boot up. During
>   │     │ compile time, a table is made of all the locations that ftrace
>   │     │ can function trace, and this table is linked into the kernel
>   │     │ image. When this is enabled, functions can be individually
>   │     │ enabled, and the functions not enabled will not affect
>   │     │ performance of the system.
>   │     │
>   │     │ See the files in /sys/kernel/debug/tracing:
>   │     │   available_filter_functions
>   │     │   set_ftrace_filter
>   │     │   set_ftrace_notrace
>   │     │
>   │     │ This way a CONFIG_FUNCTION_TRACER kernel is slightly larger,
>   but
>   │     │ otherwise has native performance as long as no tracing is
>   active.

Check out the last statement above.
(I've also (once) verified that ftrace overhead is indeed very low).

Next, I've cobbled together a sheet enumerating various Linux debug and performance monitoring -type tools here:
[LINUX TOOLS FOR THE SERIOUS SYSTEMS PROGRAMMER](http://kaiwantech.wordpress.com/2013/12/28/linux-tools-for-the-serious-systems-programmer/)

HTH.